# How do I print out an entire thread in Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

I want to print out an entire thread in Google Groups. The thread has 40+ responses. How do I do that?

Here is the thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrumalliance/4DRtljImycY

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any feature built into the site. Have you tried the browser's print function?

Answer (score 1):

At least in Google Chrome, printing with the browser function only gives the first page of the discussion.  One ugly workaround is this:

- Choose the "Compact" view.  (It may work with other views but I haven't tried it.)
- Right-click on any message and select "Inspect element."  A window will appear with a whole bunch of "`div`" entries in the upper left pane.
- Scroll up to the line that starts with `<div class="JRVGTC-b-G"`.  Watch out for the `b-G` - it's important.
- Right click on that line and select "Edit as HTML".
- Hit `Ctrl+A` and then `Ctrl+C` to copy all the text to the clipboard.
- Open *Notepad*.  Paste  the text into an empty file.
- Hit File | Save.  Change "Save as type" to "All Files."  Give the file a name ending in "`.htm`".
- Go to the folder where you saved the new file and double-click on the file.  Your browser should open it and display the text, without the fancy formatting.
- Print from the browser.

Easy, right?

(PS - "JRVGRC-b-G" will probably change at some point.  If it does, you can look for a `div` row with `height: <some large number>` in it, or try working your way up until you find the right one.)

Comment: +1 for "Easy, right?". I can do this, but it makes me want to cry. Also, I didn't actually give you +1 because I don't want other people to follow these instructions, but I know you worked really hard on this and thank you.

Comment: This looses images and some formatting (e.g. inline replies). A better solution would be to just edit the html until the page's own scrolling system is disabled. But I tried in vain.